# how to get the index of numpy.random.choice? - python

Tags: python, random, numpy

Is it possible to modify the numpy.random.choice function in order to make it return the index of the chosen element? 
Basically, I want to create a list and select elements randomly without replacement

```
import numpy as np
>>> a = [1,4,1,3,3,2,1,4]
>>> np.random.choice(a)
>>> 4
>>> a
>>> [1,4,1,3,3,2,1,4]
```

`a.remove(np.random.choice(a))` will remove the first element of the list with that value it encounters (`a[1]` in the example above), which may not be the chosen element (eg, `a[7]`).

Comment: It may not be the chosen element, but it seems like two cases are indistinguishable.

Comment: `enumerate` would probably work

Comment: @Rob: Not really. After I create the list it's important that it remains in the same order, whichever element I remove.

Comment: ... there should be a function np.random.argchoice(...)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's one way to find out the *index* of a randomly selected element:

```
import random # plain random module, not numpy's
random.choice(list(enumerate(a)))[0]
=> 4      # just an example, index is 4
```

Or you could retrieve the element *and* the index in a single step:

```
random.choice(list(enumerate(a)))
=> (1, 4) # just an example, index is 1 and element is 4
```

Comment: This is not working for me. It gives me a "ValueError: a must be 1-dimensional"

Comment: I copy/pasted the your code and the list above, and I still get the same error. Is it working with you?

Comment: `list(enumerate(a))` produces a list of tuples, which is considered a 2D array-like object. This won't work.

Comment: @HappyPy you're right, I tested it with `random.choice`, not `np.random.choice`. If you must absolutely use `np.random.choice`, then my answer won't work and I'll delete it. But if you use plain old `random.choice` (from the `random` module), it'll work.

Comment: That's because you're using np, @user2357112, example is with `random.choice`

Comment: @Óscar López: Yes, now it works. But how would I remove the chosen number from "a" then? Will I have to assign random.choice(list(enumerate(a)))[0] to a variable and then use it as an index for "a"?

Comment: @HappyPy yes, assign the index to a variable (let's call it `idx`) and then you can delete it like this: `del(a[idx])`

Comment: @HappyPy always my pleasure! :)

Comment: Strong warning, this is going to have terrible performance, which is one of the primary reasons people use numpy in the first place. You're iterating over an entire array. It would be cheaper to just generate a random integer between 0 and the length of the list rather than this.

Answer (score 18):

Regarding your first question, you can work the other way  around, randomly choose from the index of the array `a` and then fetch the value.

```
>>> a = [1,4,1,3,3,2,1,4]
>>> a = np.array(a)
>>> random.choice(arange(a.size))
6
>>> a[6]
```

But if you just need random sample without replacement, `replace=False` will do. Can't remember when it was firstly added to `random.choice`, might be 1.7.0. So if you are running very old `numpy` it may not work. Keep in mind the default is `replace=True`

Comment: No need to make a list and choose from it in this case, just do `np.random.randint(0,a.size)`, unless I suppose many mutually exclusive choices are needed.

Comment: @askwchan, right! What was I thinking. `np.random.randint(0,a.size, size=size_you_want)` will be enough.

Comment: @CT Zhu: I get a AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'size'

Comment: Oh, `a` is a list, not a `array`. Put convert it to `array` first. I forgot to copy 1 line.

Comment: @askwchan, oh, no. Your method will always become sampling with replacement. HappyPy really needs that `replace=False`, so a once a element is sampled it will not sampled again.

Comment: Quite brilliant answer - it's nice because one can recycle the indices for different arrays - e.g. machine learning `X[ia,:]` and `y[ia]` - you should add that use case to your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

```
numpy.random.choice(a, size=however_many, replace=False)
```

If you want a sample without replacement, just ask numpy to make you one. Don't loop and draw items repeatedly. That'll produce bloated code and horrible performance.

Example:

```
>>> a = numpy.arange(10)
>>> a
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
>>> numpy.random.choice(a, size=5, replace=False)
array([7, 5, 8, 6, 2])
```

On a sufficiently recent NumPy (at least 1.17), you should use the new randomness API, which fixes a longstanding performance issue where the old API's `replace=False` code path unnecessarily generated a complete permutation of the input under the hood:

```
rng = numpy.random.default_rng()
result = rng.choice(a, size=however_many, replace=False)
```

Comment: I don't understand how would this work. What's "a" in this case? Could you provide an example please?

Comment: @HappyPy: `a` is exactly the same thing it is in your code; it's the array-like object we want a sample from. `size` is the number of elements we want in the sample, and `replace=False` asks for a sample without replacement. The result will be a 1D array of shape `(however_many,)` containing the sample you wanted.

Comment: The sample is already "a". I want to work directly with "a" so that I can control how many elements are still left and perform other operations with "a".

Comment: @HappyPy: That sounds like you're using numpy all wrong. If `a` is already a random sample, but you want to draw elements from `a` without replacement, you're essentially drawing another random sample from `a`. If you *really, really* want to successively remove elements from `a`, numpy is unlikely to help you.

Answer (score 4):

This is a bit in left field compared with the other answers, but I thought it might help what it sounds like you're trying to do in a slightly larger sense. You can generate a random sample without replacement by shuffling the indices of the elements in the source array :

```
source = np.random.randint(0, 100, size=100) # generate a set to sample from
idx = np.arange(len(source))
np.random.shuffle(idx)
subsample = source[idx[:10]]
```

This will create a sample (here, of size 10) by drawing elements from the source set (here, of size 100) without replacement.

You can interact with the non-selected elements by using the remaining index values, i.e.:

```
notsampled = source[idx[10:]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe late but it worth to mention this solution because I think the simplest way to do so is:

```
a = [1, 4, 1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 4]
n = len(a)
idx = np.random.choice(list(range(n)), p=np.ones(n)/n)
```

It means you are **choosing from the indices** uniformly. In a more general case, you can do a weighted sampling (and return the index) in this way:

```
probs = [.3, .4, .2, 0, .1]
n = len(a)
idx = np.random.choice(list(range(n)), p=probs)
```

If you try to do so for so many times (e.g. 1e5), the histogram of the chosen indices would be like `[0.30126 0.39817 0.19986 0.      0.10071]` in this case which is correct.

Anyway, you should choose from the indices and use the values (if you need) as their probabilities.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `choice`, you can also simply [`random.shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) your array, i.e.

```
random.shuffle(a)  # will shuffle a in-place
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment:

> The sample is already `a`. I want to work directly with `a` so that I can control how many elements are still left and perform other operations with `a`. – HappyPy

it sounds to me like you're interested in working with `a` after `n` randomly selected elements are removed.  Instead, why not work with `N = len(a) - n` randomly selected elements from `a`?  Since you want them to still be in the original order, you can select from indices like in @CTZhu's answer, but then sort them and grab from the original list:

```
import numpy as np
n = 3 #number to 'remove'
a = np.array([1,4,1,3,3,2,1,4])
i = np.random.choice(np.arange(a.size), a.size-n, replace=False)
i.sort()
a[i]
#array([1, 4, 1, 3, 1])
```

So now you can save that as `a` again:

```
a = a[i]
```

and work with `a` with `n` elements removed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution, just choose from the range function.

```
import numpy as np
a = [100,400,100,300,300,200,100,400]
I=np.random.choice(np.arange(len(a)))
print('index is '+str(I)+' number is '+str(a[I]))
```

Answer (score 0):

The question title versus its description are a bit different. I just wanted the answer to the title question which was getting only an (integer) index from `numpy.random.choice()`. Rather than any of the above, I settled on `index = numpy.random.choice(len(array_or_whatever))` (tested in numpy 1.21.6).

Ex:

```py
import numpy
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
i = numpy.random.choice(len(a))
```

The problem I had in the other solutions were the unnecessary conversions to `list` which would recreate the entire collection in a new object (slow!).

Reference: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html?highlight=choice#numpy.random.choice

Key point from the docs about the first parameter `a`:

> `a`: 1-D array-like or int
> If an ndarray, a random sample is generated from its elements. **If an int**, the random sample is generated as if it were np.arange(a)

Since the question is very old then it's possible I'm coming at this from the convenience of newer versions supporting exactly what myself and the OP wanted.