# How to retrieve the index of a non-unique element in a list randomly chosen with np.random.choice?

Tags: python, numpy

If I have a list such as:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5]
```

And I want to choose a random element from this list using `np.random.choice`, and let's say that results in me getting the value 3, how am I supposed to get the correct index of the element 3 and not just automatically the first 3 that appears?

I know for list of unique values, I can use `.index` to get it, but not sure how to go about for non-unique values.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find all occurrences of an element in a list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294179/how-to-find-all-occurrences-of-an-element-in-a-list)

Comment: So, are you trying to get the index of a `3` picked at random?

Comment: Then you choose the index randomly and get the item from the index.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get the index of numpy.random.choice? - python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18794390/how-to-get-the-index-of-numpy-random-choice-python)

Comment: Hi Julien and Lukasz, so np.random.choice and then getting the index would work if the value that was outputted is non-unique. Then I would get the correct index.

Comment: To @Divakar, yes if that 3 was picked at random, how would I know whether it was the 3 from index 2 or index 3?

Answer (score 6):

You can't, of course. If you need the index for a picked value, you'd rather choose a random index first and then retrieve the desired list element:

```
index = random.randrange(0, len(a))
value = a[index]
```

Note that using the `.index` approach is not that good even if the element is unique, since that method has to perform a linear search on the list (i.e. comparing each element with your value until it is found out)